# Regex to remove text after angle brackets

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex that will extract the names from an email "From" header. I had a regex that worked good for most email clients but I just noticed that another email client send the header over slightly different thus breaking the regular expression. My initial thought was to extract everything inside of Double or Single quotes but this does not work anymore because it does not have to be quoted.

I was using the regular expression `([""'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1` to extract the text between the quotes. However now I think the best course of action would be to remove the text inside of the angle brackets leaving me with only "Testing Person" without quotes and preferably without the second occurrence after the comma although this is not necessary.

Below is the two strings I am trying to extract the names from:

```
Testing Person <testing.person@example.com>,Testing Person <testing.person@example.com>
"Testing Person" <testing.person@example.com>,"Testing Person" <testing.person@example.com>
```

I tried using this but I can't seem to figure out how to tell it how to only capture the first half of the string up to the angle bracket `(?!([^<|>])).*`

Comment: What means `[^<|>]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positive look ahead, to take the name before the < char. e.g. q(?=u) means match q that is followed by a u. The following example, take all the names before <. It handles the quotes and white spaces.

Example:

```
string pattern = @"([\w]+[\w\s]*)(?=[\'""\s]*<{1})";
var matches = Regex.Matches(
                  "Testing Person <testing.person@example.com>,
                  Testing Person <testing.person@example.com>, 
                  \"Testing Person\" <testing.person@example.com>,
                  'Testing Person' <testing.person@example.com>", 
                  pattern);
```

Explanation:

{1} : exactly one occurrence

*: zero or more occurrence

+: one or more occurrence

\w: alphanumeric

\s: white space

[]: define a range

[\'""\s]: single quote, double quote and white space are accepted in the range, \ is escape char

x(?=<): match x that comes before <

x(?=[\'""\s]*<{1}): matches x which is followed by one occurrence of <, there could be zero or more single quote, double quote or white space before <

([\w]+[\w\s]*): one or more alphanumeric followed by zero or more alphanumeric or white space. I have added [\w]+ to ensure we do not match empty strings.

you can have a look here for explanation about positive look ahead: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is more straightforward to use capturing groups than lookaround, if possible. You can use the following pattern:
`(['"]?)([A-Za-z ]+)\1 <.+>`

And simply replace with `\2`

https://regex101.com/r/ISEEeo/1